# parameters in Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have linked my Xcode project to a firebase real-time database. To read from the database, I have used a completion handler a variable can be returned from the closure. However, I want to add a parameter (the variable accounts and username) when I call the completion handler.

The following is my code of the closure and completion handler:

```
func getAccounts(completion: @escaping (_ noOfAccounts: Int) -> Void){
            ref.child("Accounts").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) {(snapshot:DataSnapshot) in
                let noOfAccounts = snapshot.value as? Int
                completion(noOfAccounts!)
            }
}


getAccounts() { (AccountNo) -> () in
            print(AccountNo)
}
```

When I call the function "getAccounts", I want to add a parameter for Username and Account, can anyone help me with this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you seeking the correct syntax for adding parameters to your method?

Comment: The code in the question reads a node *Accounts* and get's its direct value, which is an int, and returns it via the completion handler. There's no Username or Account information in *Accounts* to return and no indication as if you want t pass in those parameters or return them, Can you please include your Firebase structure (as text please) and also clarify your question as the provided code is unrelated to the question. Where are you expecting to get Username and Account from?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to read my question jay, sorry for the confusion but I managed to work it out with the help of Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t know what type account is. But the syntax should be something like this:

```
func getAccounts(username: String, account: String, completion: @escaping (_ noOfAccounts: Int) -> Void){
        ref.child("Accounts").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) {(snapshot:DataSnapshot) in
            let noOfAccounts = snapshot.value as? Int
            completion(noOfAccounts!)
        }
}
```

Calling the method will then look like this:

```
getAccounts(username: ”someUsername”, account: ”someAccount”) { noOfAccounts in
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: thank you so much, this is exactly what I was looking for! big help!